# why OpenFileDialog1->ShowDialog don't work?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, openfiledialog

I am working for a interface in Visual Studio 2012 VC++ Windows forms. I use `OpenFileDialog`, but i don't understand why `ShowDialog` doesn't work.

I added the `openFileDialog1` in my interface.
then in the code, i just write

```
private: System::Void Ouvrir_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();
}
```

The dialog box did not appear and my interface is blocked also...

Comment: You need the [STAThreadAttribute] attribute on your Main() function to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFileDialog likely ended up opening or getting stuck *behind* your form since you did not specify a parent. Your experience of the interface being blocked is consistent with this theory.

Try the [`ShowDialog(IWin32Window^ owner)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a55b9ds.aspx) instead, passing the current window as the parent. This will make sure the dialog stays on top of your form, and it should always show:

```
openFileDialog1->ShowDialog( this );
```

Comment: @Weiwei Fair enough. It's something I've seen happen before so I thought I would post it as an answer